# Magento Send Attachment With Order Email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

We need to attach a custom pdf file with an order email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below extension which provide free to attachment with order.

Magento1 :

https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-email-attachments.html

If you want in Magento2 :

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments

**hope its helpful to you**

Comment: but this is for Magento1 only..

Comment: yes, add in tag like magento1.9 that's why i share you m1 link

Comment: Oh yea, sorry my bad. Question was shared by Chirag not me. I was just checking.